# Android widgets are incorrectly positioned

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android programming, and started using Android Studio to develop a very simple app. However, using the "Design" view in the XML file, the widgets are not being correctly placed.

See the image - there are two widgets - Button and TextView. They are positioned at different places within the "Design" view, but they show in the left top corner in the emulator.

Why is this happening?[image: UI snapshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your button view is using tools attribute which is only work in preview not on device make sure you remove them and use appropriate attributes

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:text="adhfbkj"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

    <Button
        android:text="button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: How would I position the button to a custom position on the screen, unattached to the "tv" TextView?

Comment: if can position your button with respect to parent or other view if you add any

Comment: you can read further here https://medium.com/@loutry/guide-to-constraintlayout-407cd87bc013